# Basic routing doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, laravel

I'm starting Laravel and the following works fine:

```
Route::get('users', function()
{
    return 'Users!';
});
```

However this does not work:

```
$test = function()
{
    return 'Users!';
}

Route::get('users', $test);
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning on error reporting (`error_reporting(-1);`) so PHP would throw a syntax error.  You are missing a semicolon:

```
$test = function()
{
    return 'Users!';
};
```

The reason a semicolon is necessary is because you are setting a value to a variable.  If you are just defining a function (`function test() {}`), you don't need the semicolon.

---

To actually use a defined function like `function test() {}`, you will need to set up [Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers) in Laravel.  For example:

*app/controllers/TestController.php*

```
class TestController extends BaseController
{

    public function index()
    {
        return 'Users!';
    }

}
```

*app/routes.php*

```
Route::get('users', 'TestController@index');
```

**Note:** you will need to run `composer dump-autoload` anytime you add a new class (i.e. `TestController`) to your repository.

Comment: Your answer is correct. I'll be able to accept it in 10 minutes. Do I add error_reporting(-1); to routes.php?

Comment: If I define it as a function function test() {} Does the get look like this? Route::get('users', test());

Comment: You should be able to add it to the top of your `routes.php`; however, for a more permanent fix I'd recommend editing your `PHP.ini`.

Comment: See my update for using controllers with your routes.

Comment: Your answer tells me everything I wanted to know. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help, enjoy Laravel.